# How should one know the vote-count of a user when he asked a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-count

How would one know the vote-count of a user has when he/she asked a particular question or answered a particular question? Right now it just shows the current status of the user for a past question, which is normal though.

But in case I would want to know the status of the user when he asked a question or answer, how would I find that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find out what someone's historical reputation was at the specific time a question or answer was posted? Or do you want to find out how many votes someone has cast when a particular question or answer was posted?

Comment: @sarnold: Its exactly the former, "find out what someone's historical reputation was at the specific time a question or answer was posted?". And I think the latter can be found using timeline feature right.

Comment: Why does this matter?

Comment: @CodyGray: Insatiable curiosity I would say.

Comment: It seems like a weird feature to add just to satisfy your curiosity. Like Tom suggests, you can calculate this for yourself by looking at the dates and the user's "reputation" tab in his/her profile. But there's no place in the UI that it is displayed to you, and I'm not convinced there should be such a place.

Comment: I never asked for this feature, it was just a question that popped in my mind for which the answer should have been a "no, you cant find that out (unless you can manually minus all the votes till that question)". And yes I saw Tom's point too, but that is not the answer to the question right.

Comment: @CodyGray: [You can](http://stackexchange.com/users/152400/cody-gray?tab=reputation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you mean the vote count on the question/answer:

Questions have [a timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/125124/timeline), where you can follow this information.

Changing

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125124/how-should-one-know-the-vote-count-of-a-user-when-he-asked-a-question
```

into

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/125124/timeline
```

allows you to follow the timeline of your question.

So, replace `questions` by `posts` and the end by `timeline`.

Go try it for a [more busy question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/121287/timeline), it takes a bit of practice to be able to read it properly...

### If you mean the user's reputation:

You can see this under the [`reputation` tab on the profile of a user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145350/tom-wijsman?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2012-03-05%2003:27:42Z).

However, it doesn't show totals; so you'd have to count how his reputation has changed over time.

Although, the [network profile `reputation` tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/19908/tom-wijsman?tab=reputation) shows a nice graph where you can get a better idea if the question has been asked long ago and it becomes unfeasible to use the user's profile.

Comment: I think the OP means the latter.

Comment: @tom: timeline shows more of downvotes and upvotes history for that question over a period, but it is not showing the specific vote-count of a particular user who made an impact(edit, comment or answer) to that question at that point of time.

Comment: @bbc: Voting is anonymous, you can't see what someone has voted on.

Comment: @TomWijsman: see my comment to sarnold's point under the question.

Comment: @TomWijsman: Thanks for the update, reputation tab shows the vote-count summary per question and per day. My point is to find out the reputation at that specific point of time when a user asked a question or posted an answer for a question. As I see it, there is no way to find that out.

Comment: @bbc: See my *very last* sentence. You can reach that by clicking "network profile" on someone's user profile and then clicking "reputation".

Comment: @TomWijsman: I see that, you are right. Looks like the graph only works for those profiles with above 200 rep.