# How to get a Moderator attention to a suggestion?

Tags: support

I have been a user on Meta for a couple of weeks now and I have seen some very good questions asked and answered. But there are some questions I would like the Moderator staff to see and consider combining into a FAQ, particularly, the question of how to view the vote timeline.

If someone who happened to know had not come along, there would have been no way for the asker to find out (that I can see) simply studying the site.

After all I read the FAQs, and it's not there. How should I "flag" something for *positive* Moderator attention? And if there is no way, could we make one?

**EDIT**

This is the question that sparked this one and that I would like to see in the FAQs:

[How should one know the vote-count of a user when he asked a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125124/)

Comment: What meta questions? Could you link to them? It might be better to just come up with these in your meta question than to go flag random things that might already be in the FAQ or might not be FAQ-worthy...

Comment: I'm trying to find it...

Comment: I always thought the general process was to make those topics [meta-tag:faq-proposed].

Comment: Will that receive gain their attention?

Comment: @SamStar Yes, but be sure you don't reinterpret an existing post as faq proposed when it wasn't. I suggest you write a new post suggesting a particular addition to the [meta-tag:faq] and tag it [meta-tag:faq-proposed], you request will be up/down voted to reflect how to feel about that suggestion.

Comment: @StevenJeuris good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please update the question title as to reflect your intended question better?

Comment: @StevenJeuris There you go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always thought the general process was to make those topics [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed).

> Questions that are proposing new or amended entries for the FAQ should
>   use this tag.
>
> Changes to the FAQ need to be discussed before being implemented.
>
> Use this tag to mark proposed changes so that they can be tracked.

Just be sure you don't reinterpret an existing post as faq proposed when it wasn't. I suggest you write a new post suggesting a particular addition to the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and tag it [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed), your request will be up/down voted to reflect how they feel about that suggestion.

It might also not hurt explicitly stating it is a faq proposed. Sometimes people don't notice the tags.